# Flattening a tree structure in Lisp

Tags: list, recursion, tree, lisp

I was struggling with flattening a tree structure. I was doing it recursively by comparing each atomic symbol to the rest in the tree but, a friend of mine suggested the following code which I think looks cleaner. I just don't understand the line:

```
((atom tree)(list tree))
```

I understand what each of them do individually, I also know that the loop below takes a list or it causes an error, which I suspect has a lot to due with the reason we're turning the symbol into a list if atom returns true. But I still don't feel like I fully understand the code.

```
(defun flatten (tree)
(cond ((null tree)
     nil
     )
    ((atom tree)(list tree))
    (t
     (loop for a in tree appending (flatten a)))))
```

An explanation would terrific if anyone could spare the time? Thanks!

Comment: You might also be interested in [flatten list in lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13171928/1281433), [Flatten Nests Function in Lisp - need help understanding](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10465096/1281433) (which actually has almost _identical_ code (modulo formatting) to what you've provided, maybe that's where your friend found it), and [Common Lisp - flatting a list that may contain symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10638379/1281433) (which also has code similar to yours).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is rather poorly formatted.  In the first part of your question, it's not at all clear why

```
((atom tree) (list tree))
```

would appear in *any* Common Lisp code, since it looks like an attempt to call `(atom tree)`, get a function back, and call that function with `(list tree)`.  In context, with proper formatting, it's clearer:

```
(defun flatten (tree)
  (cond 
   ((null tree) nil)
   ((atom tree)(list tree))
   (t (loop for a in tree
            appending (flatten a)))))
```

It's one clause in a `cond`.  It says that *if* `tree` is an atom (which could be a symbol, a number, a vector, etc., anything else that isn't a `cons`), then return `(list tree)`.  As [larsmans explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20144081/1281433), `flatten` should always return a list, and this ensures that `(flatten 3)`, for instance, will return `(3)`.  Since the `(loop for a in tree ...)` will work for any `tree` that is a list, there's really no need to have a case for `(null tree)`, since `nil/()` *is* a list.  This definition could be simplified to:

```
(defun flatten (tree)
  (if (atom tree)
      (list tree)
      (loop for a in tree
            appending (flatten a)))))
```

There are some similar questions out there on Stack Overflow, and some have almost identical code to what you posted (modulo the formatting).  Did the friend was basing a suggestion on one of those. At any rate, for the sake of completeness, you might have a look at:

- [flatten list in lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13171928/1281433)
- [Flatten Nests Function in Lisp - need help understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10465096/1281433) (almost identical code)
- [Common Lisp - flatting a list that may contain symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10638379/1281433) (similar code)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The second flatten function is throwing an error due to an extra parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

> I also know that the loop below takes a list or it causes an error, which I suspect has a lot to due with the reason we're turning the symbol into a list if atom returns true.

Spot on. The postcondition of `flatten` is that its result is always a flat list (not "a flat list or an atom"), so that the recursive calls need only handle one data type.

Answer (score 0):

`((atom tree)(list tree))` is a piece of syntax which cannot be understood on its own. It belongs to the `cond` syntax: it is known in Lisp culture as a *cond pair*.  The cond pair says that if the `(atom tree)` expression is true, then `(list tree)` is evaluated. `cond` then terminates and returns that value.

The *cond pair* terminology is imprecise because in Common Lisp, the cond clauses are n-ary. They do not have to be pairs. The additional forms can be omitted entirely, so that the clauses are singleton items, allowing `cond` to be used like `or`:

```
(cond (a) (b) (c) ...) <==> (or a b c)
```

Here, `a` is evaluated. If it yields true (a value other than nil), then `cond` stops and returns the value of `a`. Otherwise it tests `b` and so on.  That's exactly what the `or` does.

There can be two or more forms:

```
(cond (a p r s) (b t u) (c x y) ...)
```

If `a` yields true, then `p` `r` and `s` are evaluated, and the value of `s` is returned out of `cond`. If `a` yields false, then `b` is tried and so on.

`cond` is basically a generalized `or`, for which you pay with extra parentheses: try this case, *or* else try that case, etc.